# Sex, Dose, and Repeated Measures Analysis

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, spss, biostatistics

I am testing the hypothesis that male and female have a different timeline of withdrawal behavior, such that either males or females experience greater withdrawal symptoms from morphine across 12-24-36 hours. As well as testing the hypothesis that ketamine will reduce the severity of withdrawal symptoms.

For my experiment I am looking at male and female rats, the dose of ketamine is a between subjects factor with one group getting saline, a group getting 10mg/kg and a group getting 20mg/kg. Then they were observed at three different time periods (12-24-36 hours), time being within subjects.

Certain behaviors were recorded across each time period. For example: The number of wall climbs was recorded at 12-24-36 hours, the number of paw tremors, rearing, and other behaviors associated with morphine withdrawal in a rat. What would be the appropriate statistical test to run and follow up tests?

Comment: The way my data is currently formatted in SPSS might also be an issue. I have it formatted as Sex coded as 0 for female and 1 for male. Dose: 0,10,20. Then each behavior is in its own column for each the time period it was recorded. Ex: WallClimbing_12, WallClimbing_24, WallClimbing_36. For behaviors that occurred at 12-24-36 hours

Comment: Maybe also a short explanation of what is *withdrawal symptoms*.

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the outcome variables. Wall climbs and paw tremors seem to be integer count variables; what about rearing and the "other behaviors"? Are those numbers the total numbers throughout each 12-hour time period, or over a shorter time period near each of 12, 24, and 36 hours post withdrawal? Might you have the actual time of each count-type event available; e.g., the time of each wall climb or tremor? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.